# Html Parser using java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a validating HTML parser implemented in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904293/is-there-a-validating-html-parser-implemented-in-java)

Hi,

Is there is any API which parse the HTML text using java.

All the function should in the format of Objects

e.g. In the following text i want to Parse the HTML file
and parser should return me the list of tags , attribute ..

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" value="100">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please search before you ask. There are **tons** of questions just like this.

Comment: and tons of google results for "parse HTML java"

Comment: @Bozho: that alone is not a reason not to post on here.

Comment: it is for posting a question like "is there an API" - there is. It isn't a reason for not asking "which is a _good_ parsing API"

Comment: @Bozho: When someone asks "is there an API" they **always** mean "which API should I use". Assuming anything else is just willfully ignoring the real question. It's not a good way to state that question, but it's also not useful to anyone to claim not to realize that something else was meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [HTML/XML Parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java) and [Is there a validating HTML parser implemented in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904293/is-there-a-validating-html-parser-implemented-in-java) and finally [Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best)

These should answer your question nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Comprehensive list [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)

Answer (score 0):

Regex's should work just fine.... *cough*

Comment: +1 for humor!
Also see the top response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Haha, yeah - I remember reading that on the Coding Horror blog.  Good stuff indeed :)